# How to pass variable from MySQL to SWF

Tags: javascript, php, actionscript-3, flash, swfobject

I am trying to pass an ssoTicket from MySQL through a webpage and into a SWF file.

The bellow code results in null in the server log, but when I set an ssoTicket that matches, everything works fine.

There seems to be relatively little information online.

I have printed sso_ticket and it does echo the correct string.

**Page**

```
<?php
include("global.php");
if($islogged) { ?>
<?xml version=”1.0″?>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $self['sso_ticket']; ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <script src="js/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {
            sso: "<?php echo $self['sso_ticket']; ?>" 
        };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            scale: "noScale",
            allowFullscreen: "true",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            bgcolor: "#FFFFFF"
        };
        var attributes = {
            id:"E4"
        };
        swfobject.embedSWF("ac.swf", "altContent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
    <style>
        html, body { height:100%; }
        body { margin:0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="altContent">
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img 
            src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" 
            alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

**SWF**

```
var ssoTicket:String = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters["sso"];
```

**SWF With pre-set ssoTicket**

```
var ssoTicket:String = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters["sso"];          
if (ssoTicket == "" || ssoTicket == null) ssoTicket = "73a448e7e4a3314d2d1a3f33588df9b8";
```

Comment: Show the code that uses `flashvars` variable?

Comment: you need to actually do something with `flashvars` ... `flashvars` is not a majick name

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject to wrap the SWF and pass your `flashers`

Comment: Please see the question for the full source, I believe the SWF is correctly wrapped?  Thank you for all the comments thus far.

Comment: @SushiHangover any more suggestions?

Comment: @SaucedApples I do a rollback to revision 2 of your post because your HTML (& PHP) and AS3 codes are fine. Did you explain more the problem ? What did you got exactly as result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flashvars should be a set of `name=value` pairs (with pairs separated by an `&`, not being used in your example currently but in case you add more flashvars).

So something like this will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    flashvars.sso = "<?php echo $self['sso_ticket']; ?>";
    var params = {};
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("ac.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "800", "600", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

There is a html generator within the swfobject project that you can plug all your values into and it will gen your static or dynamic html code for you to cut/paste into your code ([swfobjectgen.html](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/blob/master/swfobject_generator/html/index.html)).

Then this should work inside your SWF to assign your ticket #:

```
var ssoTicket:String = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.sso;
```

Comment: I'm afraid this just shows the Get Adobe Flash Player button.

Comment: ? Use the code generator in the project to generate the entire dynamic content for you and try that.

Comment: The issue appears to be with this line `flashvars.sso = "<?php echo $self['sso_ticket']; ?>";` but i am unsure how to insert PHP correctly into the flashvar

Comment: OP's HTML, PHP & AS3 codes are fine. This answer didn't add anything to OP's original code.

Comment: If you have a different solution, please post it but don't downvote my question and revert it when it worked for me @akmozo

Comment: @SaucedApples Your posted codes are fine. I didn't post an answer because your question is unclear, even I don't see any problem in your code.

Comment: Well to begin with, I marked this answer as correct because the advice supplied with swfobject answered my question, and well as the correct line for the main.as file in the answer, they appear to fix the issue.  Why post on a question you think was fine before when it wasnt, I'd like my +2 rep please

Comment: @SaucedApples You should know that there is no difference between this answer and your code : `var flashvars = { sso: "some_value" };` is exactly the same as : `var flashvars;  flashvars.sso = "some_value";` and `LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.sso` is exactly the same as : `LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters['sso']` ...

Comment: When I made the changes, I saw the sso from my database enter my server log whereas before it was printing null.  Again, -2 his answer not my question

Comment: @SaucedApples I don't know what's your "server log" and how you did got a non-null value there and its relation with this question. You should know that we can answer a question just according to what we can see and understand, and nothing else.